# debounce not firing inside $scope.$watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I'm trying to run a function when a model variable updates in my UI but I'm also trying to throttle how often the function is executed via a debounce as the requested function fires an AJAX call. However the debounce function below just doesn't seem to be firing at all.

I originally wrote my own debounce service and have resorted to using underscores debounce method to test whether what I wrote was incorrect or not but it turns out Angular just isn't liking something below...

Using Angular's `ng-model-option` debounce method in the HTML is not an option.

```
$scope.$watch('filters.monthlyCost', function () {

    _.debounce(function () {
        console.log('lol');
    }, 1000);

});
```

There are no console errors, `console.log('lol')` just never happens.

Note: $watch **does** execute.

Comment: Is your watch executing?

Comment: @PSL yeah, $watch is executing.

Comment: You should be using model options if you want to watch on debounce, otherwise it will always fire every time the model changes even with underscore debounce. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce) returns a function (`(Function): Returns the new debounced function.`) that return value of `debounce` needs to be executed,

i.e example:

```
_.debounce(function () {
        console.log('lol');
    }, 1000)();
```

You could do:

```
$scope.$watch('monthlyCost', _.debounce(function() {
        console.log('lol');
    }, 1000));
```

Answer (score 0):

As I under stand from the docs of _.debounce (not tested)

```
$scope.$watch('filters.monthlyCost', function () {

    var logConsole = _.debounce(function () {
        console.log('lol');
        }, 1000);
    logConsole();

});
```

With your code, you are only registering a debounce function but it will not execute.